# Writing a given sequence of int's as an array of hex values in Jackson

Tags: json, jackson, integer, hex, specifications

Is it possible to make `Jackson FasterXML` library to serialize a given sequence of `Integer` values as an array of `Hex` values? That is, simply put, I would like that the code:

```java
public class SampleJson {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    JsonNode toJson(int[] values) {
        ArrayNode jsonArray = mapper.createArrayNode();
        for(int i: values)
            jsonArray.add(i);
        return jsonArray;
    }

    String toJsonString(JsonNode node) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(node);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SampleJson sj = new SampleJson();
        int[] values = {1, 2, 0x10, 0x20};
        try {
            System.out.println(sj.toJsonString(sj.toJson(values)));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            System.err.println("Something goes wrong...");
        }
    }
}
```

would produce `[0x1,0x2,0x10,0x10]`, not `[1,2,16,32]` as it does now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question we need to take a look at [`JSON` specification](https://www.json.org/) and what it says about numbers:

> A number is very much like a C or Java number, except that the **octal**
>   and **hexadecimal** formats are not used.

So, to write numbers in hexadecimal format you need to implement custom serialiser and write them as `string` primitives:

```
["0x1","0x2","0x10","0x10"]
```