# Converting Json containing hex value to POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson, hex

I need to parse below `Json` to POJO class

```
{
    "number_1": [0x5023000000000000], 
    "number_2": [0x5024000000000000], 
    "number_3": [0x2fdcfdf3b645a1cb], 
    "number_4": [0x1000000000000000], 
    "number_5": [0x0000020000000000]
}
```

but the problem is that the values are hexadecimals and hence I get below error :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed
```

I use Jackson library for parsing Json. How can I parse above Json?. Is there any alternative for Jackson for doing this?

> Note : The Json is generated from 3rd party library. I cannot have
>   access to alter the Json structure

Comment: Have a look at jsonlint.com, this does not seem to be valid json

Comment: Similar to [Writing a given sequence of int's as an array of hex values in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57452900/writing-a-given-sequence-of-ints-as-an-array-of-hex-values-in-jackson/57453552#57453552)